# How to understand the bytes object returned from hash.digest()?

Tags: python, string

I was wondering about the bytes object returned from:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(b'foo').digest()
>>> b',&\xb4kh\xff\xc6\x8f\xf9\x9bE<\x1d0A4\x13B-pd\x83\xbf\xa0\xf9\x8a^\x88bf\xe7\xae'
```

The documentation states:

> This is a bytes object of size digest_size which may contain bytes in the whole range from 0 to 255.

Is this the bytes version of:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(b'foo').hexdigest()
>>>'2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae'
```

?
If so, why do both representation not lineup like for example:

```
>>> 'foo'
>>> b'foo'
```

?
This is probably related to why:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(b'foo').hexdigest().decode('hex')
```

does not work?

Comment: `str` and `bytes` are different types, though `bytes` are displayed as strings preceded by the character `b`. If a given byte falls into printable ASCII, then that ascii character is displayed; otherwise, it displays an ASCII escape sequence like `\xff`.

Comment: c.f. (in Python 3)  `''.join(format(i,'x') for i in hashlib.sha256(b'foo').digest())`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the bytes version of this HEX string:

```
>>> hashlib.sha256(b'foo').hexdigest()
>>>'2c26b46b68ffc68ff99b453c1d30413413422d706483bfa0f98a5e886266e7ae'
```

Hash functions (md5, sha1, sha256) return binary data. That's why they're returning byte arrays in the python implementation. `hexdigest` is usually used if you want to send the value to an API, or print it for debugging purposes. But hash functions return bits (in form of array bytes).

As an example, take a look at the [md5 function definition from WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). You'll see that its output are bits as per the first paragraph:

> The MD5 message-digest algorithm is a widely used hash function
> producing a 128-bit hash value